# How to test a React Component with Props in TypeScript using Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

So I have this React-redux + Typescript app. This is the component I'm trying to test ;

```
import React from "react";
import "./MoviesAndSeries.css";
import ListShowItem from "../ListShowItem/ListShowItem";
import { getVisibleShows } from "../../Redux/Selector";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import FilterShowItems from "../FilterShowItems/FilterShowItems";
import { State } from "../../Redux/Reducers";
import { Show } from "../../Redux/Reducers";

const Movies: React.FC<State> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="shows">
      <FilterShowItems placeholder={"movies"} />
      <div className="show__items">
        {props.movies.map((movie: Show) => {
          return <ListShowItem key={movie.title} {...movie} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export const mapStateToProps = (state: State) => {
  return {
    movies: getVisibleShows(state.movies, state.filters),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Movies);
```

this is the test code;

```
test("movies render", () => {
  const { container } = render(<Movies />);
});
```

so Typescript warns me like this " *Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<State, "series" | "filters">': series, filtersts(2739)* "

so how can I pass those properties into this test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because the redux provider is missing in the test file.
You need to configure

```
<Provider store={store}>
<Movies />
</Provider>
```

either directly in the test or create a custom Render function that wraps the render function with provider with initial store configured, so you do not have to add this to each test file.

Comment: So I wrote this code exactly, It still throws the same error..

Comment: Have you recreated the redux store ?  The store established in the test should be assembled the same way as in the actual app, with rootReducers, Intial state and so on

Comment: Should I recreate store on the test file? I just imported the actual store, didn't recreate